# Recursion help - Peter Norvig's Sudoku exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Hi I am currently going through Peter Norvig's sudoku solution (http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).

However, I have a bit of confusion with the block code below:

```
def assign(values, s, d):
    """Eliminate all the other values (except d) from values[s] and propagate.
    Return values, except return False if a contradiction is detected."""
    other_values = values[s].replace(d, '')
    if all(eliminate(values, s, d2) for d2 in other_values):
        return values
    else:
        return False

def eliminate(values, s, d):
    """Eliminate d from values[s]; propagate when values or places <= 2.
    Return values, except return False if a contradiction is detected."""
    if d not in values[s]:
        return values ## Already eliminated
    values[s] = values[s].replace(d,'')
    ## (1) If a square s is reduced to one value d2, then eliminate d2 from the peers.
    if len(values[s]) == 0:
    return False ## Contradiction: removed last value
    elif len(values[s]) == 1:
        d2 = values[s]
        if not all(eliminate(values, s2, d2) for s2 in peers[s]):
            return False
    ## (2) If a unit u is reduced to only one place for a value d, then put it there.
    for u in units[s]:
    dplaces = [s for s in u if d in values[s]]
    if len(dplaces) == 0:
        return False ## Contradiction: no place for this value
    elif len(dplaces) == 1:
        # d can only be in one place in unit; assign it there
            if not assign(values, dplaces[0], d):
                return False
    return values
```

The function `assign` receive an input of a dictionary `values` and will return `values` as well if there is no contradiction. However, in the `assign` function, I did not see any update on the dictionary `values`. My understanding is that dict `values` is updated with the `eliminate` function (and after running the code, I believe this is the case). However, this is done outside of the `assign` function and should not affect the `values` in the assign function, as it is not updated directly in the function.

Maybe you guys can give me a shed of light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `dict`s are mutable, meaning that their value can be changed.

This example is showing an anti-pattern: You shouldn't both mutate an argument *and* return it. An example is all the methods that change a `list` (`append`, `pop`, etc.) *don't* return the original list.

The `eliminate` function gets the *same* dict as in the `assign` function, and any changes in the assign function are reflected in the elimate function.

Here is an example:

```
def update(dict_, key, value):
    dict_[key] = value

d = {
    1: 2,
    3: 4
}
update(d, 1, 100)
update(d, 3, 100)

print(d[1] + d[3])  # 200
```

Comment: I see. so this is also the behaviour even if dictionary is not a global object?

Comment: @AdrianPrayoga Yes. Python args are passed by assignment. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/5754656) might explain it better.